# why on mapred-site.xml hadoop 2 there is an mapreduce.jobtracker.address property

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

YARN is the Hadoop second generation that not use the jobtracker daemon anymore, and substitute it with resource manager. But why, on mapred-site.xml hadoop 2 there is an mapreduce.jobtracker.address property?

in order to  running Hadoop MapReduce Application from Eclipse , is there  a plugin eclipse for yarn , because i find all plugins are spesified for jobtracker.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop 2 is compatible to run on a Yarn cluster as well as MR cluster .

Just in case one needs to run hadoop 2 compiled code on a NON-YARN cluster one has to specify JT url:port .

hadoop 2 in binary compatible on both MR/YARN cluster .